# Why we add bias term in L2 regularization?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to understand that how l2 regularization is implement here. In l2 regularization we add a square of weights to the loss function. But in this code we are also adding bias term. Why is it so?

```
`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nPixels])
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nPixels, nNodes1], stddev=0.01))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nNodes1])
y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nNodes1, nLabels], stddev=0.01))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nLabels]))
y = tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, nLabels])
l2_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(W1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(b1) + tf.nn.l2_loss(W2) + 
tf.nn.l2_loss(b2)
cross_entropy = 
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))    
regularized_cross_entropy = cross_entropy + beta * l2_loss`
```

Answer (score 0):

This bias is not the same we used in l2 regularization.
This is the bias we add in neural network to keep the value not equal to zero.

Comment: Does it mean my l2_loss is wrong?then how to modify it for l2 regularization?